# How to total all inputted item code (with corresponding value) using loop and array?

Tags: c++

to all programmers enthusiast and professionals out there! I am new at C++ programming. I just want to ask how am I going to approach this task in my program "purchasing item". The user was inputting an item code and this item code has a corresponding value and inputting also the quantity of this item. The program will ask "would you like to purchased another item" if the user said yes the program will loop and need to add all previous value that the user inputted. My problem is how am I going to loop this and total all value of item that the user inputted. We dont use fstream.h

p104 and p103 is an item code

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
clrscr();
int p104 = 25, order, total = 0, subtotal, p103 = 22,itemcode, quantity, back;
do{
cout<<"Enter Item Code: ";
cin>>itemcode;
cout<<"\nEnter number of quantity: ";
cin>>quantity;
cout<<subtotal;
total=total+subtotal;
cout<<"\n"<<total;
cout<<"\nWould you like to purchase other item? [Y]-yes?";
cin>>back;
  }
while(back=='Y'||back=='y');
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use getchar() after `cin>>back_;` for taking the newline character and calculate `subtotal` based on condition.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
main()
{
//clrscr();
char back_;
int p104 = 25, order, total = 0, subtotal =0, p103 = 22,itemcode, quantity;
do{
cout<<"Enter Item Code: ";
cin>>itemcode;
cout<<"\nEnter number of quantity: ";
cin>>quantity;
//cout<<subtotal;
if (itemcode == 104){
    subtotal = quantity * p104;
}else if (itemcode == 103){
    subtotal = quantity * p103;
}
total=total+subtotal;
subtotal =0;
cout<<"\n"<<total;
cout<<"\nWould you like to purchase other item? [Y]-yes?";
cin>>back_;
getchar();
  }
while(back_=='Y'||back_=='y');
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. David Weston ! You help me a lot. :D

Comment: Mr. Weston I have my codes. I done what you have told me about adding the total inputted item code . I have another problem sir, can you find it out? my problem is I cant loop my codes. I think there is something wrong in my do-while statements. I posted my new problem on my account. Thank you.

Comment: Check your question's answer. How that will helo you? @JanNavasca